# bundle install permissions denied

Tags: permissions, ruby

Hello I am working on a new ubuntu machine and when I run tasks like:

```
bundle install
```

or

```
rvm get head
```

I get errors like:

```
Downloading https://get.rvm.io
bash: line 709: /usr/local/rvm/RELEASE: Permission denied
Could not update RVM, get some help at #rvm IRC channel at freenode servers.
```

and

```
Gem::FilePermissionError: You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin directory.
An error occurred while installing rake (10.3.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.3.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I defiantly have rake installed and it shows up when I sudo gem update in the list but my bundler is not picking it up.  Do I need to enable permissions before I can run these commands? Thanks anyone who knows what exactly what my issue is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is trying to install system-wide.  Try running `export GEM_HOME=$(ruby -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')` and then run the commands. If that works, you can add this line to your .bashrc (assuming you are running bash) to make it permanent.

Comment: I ran it and it defiantly helped thanks! now I am having an rvm issue because the project was built in 2.0.0-p451 but my new machine is way past that.  I need to install that V. but am getting an error.  Going to start a new thread though to keep this place awsome<3 Thanks again!